# Str_Replace is replacing php syntax

Tags: php, html, css

### functions/SkriptParser.php

```
<?php
    $text = file_get_contents(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
    preg_match_all("/{(.*?)}/", $text, $matches);
    var_dump($matches[0]);
    echo str_replace($matches[0],"Test",$text);
?>
```

Is my current code, this is called from my index page which is here:

### index.php

```
require_once 'functions/SkriptParser.php';
```

When i open index.php it replace the correct strings [ It'll replace any string inside {} however, it seems to be replacing `<?php` and I have no clue why.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump($text);` so we can see what the value holds?

Comment: It holds my whole index.php file, i won't be able post it all as it's alot of lines but this is what var_dump displays  https://hastebin.com/wiguzucovi.xml @ChinLeung

Comment: When you say it's replacing the `<?php`, you mean the first one at the top of your `index.php`?

Comment: After further testing i don't think it's replacing the <?php as such, i think it's almost timing php out? like once the function SkriptParser.php has ran, all php code after that does not work. not to sure if the code in my SkriptParser.php file is breaking php in some way?

Comment: Did you check your error logs?

Comment: What are you even hoping this is going to do?

Comment: @miknik It'll load a page and replace every word within a curly bracket into a word i specify. So i load index.php and half way down the page is the string {Hello} it would replace that string with another string i specify, need this to happen dynamically.

Comment: Then you do that within index.php using variables...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do.

This line `$text = file_get_contents(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));`resolves to a local filename which will be the name of the script it's included in.

It won't load the page which that script would output, it will load the file without executing the code. The contents of `$text` will be a string containing the pure php content.

When I run your code from the command line and use "Here is a test of {your code}" as my string the output is:

```
{your code}<?php
require_once 'includetest.php';
print_r(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
echo "Here's a test of Test";
```

If I run it from a browser and view the source I see that too, but the browser escapes the php so it isn't rendered on the page. So (for me at least), your concept kinda works. However, the fact the code isn't executed means it will never do what you intend.

Here's what I don't really understand though. In essence within index.php what you are telling your code to do is load a script which will load another copy of index.php and replace content within it.

If you want to change the behaviour of index.php then alter the code within index.php, don't generate unsuitable output and then load another script in an attempt to parse it before returning it. Just output it the way you want the first time.

Where is the content within the `{}` that you want to remove coming from? Why do you want/need to remove it? If you can clarify exactly what your aim is then it will be easier to suggest a solution.